# page meta description in another language

Tags: typo3

I want to set an overwrite option (`description.override.field`) for the page meta description and keyword tag as in the code below:

```
page.meta {
    description = {$meta.description}
    description.override.field = description
    keywords = {$meta.keywords}
    keywords.override.field = keywords
    robots = {$meta.robots}
}
```

I only get the content of the standard language.

has anybody an idea why I do not get the content of the other language if filled out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normaly this should get translated. Go and check the following points:

- Have you translated the current viewed page - or is translation fallback active?
- Do you have configured the language correctly in typoscript? (`config.language`, `config.sys_language_uid`, etc.)
- Last: are the fields not anymore in the `[FE][pageOverlayFields]` list?

Comment: i made it this way:
description.override.data = page:description